# Is it sufficient enough to only compose a equation of nonzero value of determinant of a matrix to prove a matrix being invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

$$A:=n\times n~\text{matrix}$$

As this matrix is invertible, at least, the following are true.
$$
\begin{equation*}%uasge:&smth\\..Dont write symbol of line break at the end of row
 \begin{cases}
 \det\left(A\right)\neq 0\\
 ~\text{rank}\left(A\right)=n\\
 ~\text{any eigenvalue of}~A~~\text{is nonzero}\\
 \end{cases} 
\end{equation*}
$$

Is it ok to just derive one of them above in school test or exam,to prove that$~A~$is invertible?

*Example problem*

$\displaystyle A:=
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1&0&2&0\\
 0&1&\alpha&0\\
 1&0&1&\alpha\\
 0&1&0&1\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$

Find out the condition(s)of$~\alpha~$for A is being invertible.

$$\det\left(A\right)\neq 0~~\leftarrow~~~\text{if and only if conditon for being invertible}$$

$$\det\left(A\right)$$

$$=\det\left(
 \begin{matrix}
 1&0&2&0\\
 0&1&\alpha&0\\
 1&0&1&\alpha\\
 0&1&0&1\\
 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$=\det\left(
 \begin{matrix}
 1&0&2&0\\
 0&1&\alpha&0\\
 0&0&-1&\alpha\\
 0&1&0&1\\
 \end{matrix}\right)~~\leftarrow~~~\text{row sum operation against 3rd row from 1st row} 
$$
$$=\det\left(
 \begin{matrix}
 1&\alpha&0\\
 0&-1&\alpha\\
 1&0&1\\
 \end{matrix}\right)~~\leftarrow~~~\text{cofactor expansion about(1,1)th element} 
$$

$$\det\left(
 \begin{matrix}
 1&\alpha&0\\
 0&-1&\alpha\\
 0&-\alpha&1\\
 \end{matrix}\right)~~\leftarrow~~~\text{row sum operation against row3from row1} 
$$

$$=\det\left(
 \begin{matrix}
 -1&\alpha\\
 -\alpha&1\\
 \end{matrix}\right)\leftarrow~~~\text{cofactor expansion about(1,1)th element}
$$

$$=\det\left(
 \begin{matrix}
 1&\alpha\\
 \alpha&1\\
 \end{matrix}\right)\leftarrow~~~\text{scalar multiplication at column2}
$$

$$=\det\left(1-\alpha^{2}\right)$$

$$=\left(-1\right)\det\left(1-\alpha^{2}\right)$$

$$=\det\left(\alpha^{2}-1\right)$$

$$=\alpha^{2}-1\neq~~0\leftarrow~~~\text{condition for being invertible}$$

$$\alpha^{2}-1\neq 0~~\iff~~\alpha^{2}\neq 1~~\iff~~\alpha\neq\pm 1$$

$$\therefore~~~\alpha\neq\pm 1~~\text{is the condition}$$

The above answer is original one of mine so I can't assert that this answer is correct.

Comment: Sure, $\det(A)=\alpha^2-1$ is a fact. So $A$ is invertible if and only if $\alpha\neq \pm 1$ in any field. You have to know what you are allowed to use for your exam, of course. In particular, how to compute the determinant.

Comment: "In particular, how to compute the determinant.", what do you mean sir? I think I made no mistake of computations of determinant.

Comment: I mean, the methods to compute it should be allowed. Otherwise you just can take mathematica.